# What's the difference between `sudo -i -u user` and `sudo su - user`?

Tags: bash, sudo, su

Both commands:

```
sudo -i -u username
sudo su - username
```

Will log me in as `username` if I enter my password. Is there actually any difference between these commands?

Comment: Run `sudo -i -u username` and check your Environment Variables then run `sudo su - username` and check your Environment Variables You should see a difference

Comment: probably this answer might be of some help to you, am also trying to find the answer fot the same question. http://askubuntu.com/questions/376199/sudo-su-vs-sudo-i-vs-sudo-bin-bash-when-does-it-matter-which-is-used

Comment: There are also very significant configuration changes. If you use `sudo su`, then your PAM configuration for `su` matters in addition to your `sudoers` config; if only using `sudo`, then you're depending only on `sudo` (and all the configuration included therein by reference -- its PAM modules, its configuration, etc), whereas using `su` in addition means you're depending on *two* tools with independent behavior and configuration (and on the former to be configured to allow the latter).

Comment: Interestingly, I've just seen a case where `sudo -i -u someuser` doesn't set variables from `/etc/environment` but `sudo su - someuser` does. (`sudo -i` on this Ubuntu 14.04 system used to work.)

Answer (score 13):

The `su` command stands for "substitute user", and allows you to become different user(super user).
`sudo su` changes the current user to root but `environment settings (PATH)` would remain same. It allows user who have permissions to execute a command as the superuser or another user, as specified in the `sudoers` file.

With `sudo -i` you get a clean root shell.
The ‑i (simulate initial login) option runs the shell specified by the password database entry of the target user as a login shell. This means that login-specific resource files such as `.profile` or `.login` will be read by the shell. If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution via the shell's ‑c option. If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.

Comment: Afaik `su` stands for 'substitute user' and not 'switch user' (or even 'super user').

Comment: thank you NaN..I corrected..apologies for the typo.

Comment: "changes the current user to root but environment settings (PATH) would remain same" - actually this is not true for me

Comment: sudo su - username, in his case bash is called as login shell, so /etc/profile, .profile and .bashrc are executed and you will find yourself in users home directory with user's environment. there is difference between sudo su and sudo su - please check http://askubuntu.com/questions/376199/sudo-su-vs-sudo-i-vs-sudo-bin-bash-when-does-it-matter-which-is-used